# After app killed, I'm getting same location from onLocationChanged service

Tags: android, gps

I have been working on android app. 
Where i used background service for get location coordinates. 
It's work fine while I'm using phone even after app was killed i'm getting proper latitude and longitude. but issue is that when I do screen lock and i do not use phone for few minutes then I'm getting same location coordinates.

```
public class LocationUpdateRequestService extends Service {

    private final LocationServiceBinder binder = new LocationServiceBinder();

    private static final String TAG = "GCMTASKSERVICE";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0f;
    public Context context;

    SharedPrefsUtil prefManager;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);

            if (location != null) {
             prefManager.putString("LastCordinates", "(" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude() + ")");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        context = this;
        prefManager = new SharedPrefsUtil(this);
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForeground(12345678, getNotification());
        }
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private Notification getNotification() {

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "gps_chanel_1",
                "GPS Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "gps_chanel_1")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        return builder.build();
    }

    public class LocationServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public LocationUpdateRequestService getService() {
            return LocationUpdateRequestService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a foreground service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
......

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(text)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
 return START_STICKY;
}
```

In the Activity, start the service like the following:

```
 startForegroundService(intent);
```

This will make sure that the application keeps on running. Google added some restrictions on the services if the application is in the background.